# The following classes could not be instantiated: com.google.ads.AdView()

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, ads

I am making weather app.My code is working fine, But there ad is not showing.Below is my code:

activity_main.xml

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/ad"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
    app:adSize="BANNER"
    app:adUnitId="......" >
</com.google.ads.AdView>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
```

MainActivity.java

```
import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.ads.AdView;
.
.
.
private AdView adview;
.
.
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
  if(adview!=null)
     {
      adview.loadAd(adRequest);
     }
```

The error (classes could not be instantiated:com.google.ads.AdView) is showing in graphical layout of activity_main.xml. Searched many question,but can't find suitable answer. Please help.

Comment: You need to import GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-X.X.X.jar file to your project.

Comment: I have already import GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar file.

Answer (score 1):

Google updated something new in firebase-ads.

In your gradle file add com.google.firebase:firebase-ads

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.8.0'
}
```

more details  [how to integrate the Google Mobile Ads SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start)

Comment: I am making in eclipse, So how to add dependency. Sorry but why down voted.

Comment: refer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25123447/admob-new-adrequest-unrecognized-by-eclipse

Comment: I am doing same as answer. I am not mixing up the old/deprecated admob api with the new admob api. I have used only old admob api.